# How would I create a different permalink structure for pages and posts?

Tags: permalinks

Right now I have pages like "about", "resources", etc and the urls are /about and /resources with a custom permalink structure as /%postname%.  For "news" section it's the posts and it's at /news and that's great. The problem is I want the new stories to be /news/the-name-of-the-story not /the-name-of-the-story.  Can that be accomplished in the wp admin area? Or is that a custom .htaccess trick? Also, news is in categories and /category/category-name lists the posts in that category and the story for those should be at /category/category-name/the-name-of-the-story. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The custom permalink field on the settings->permalink screen *only* applies to Posts. Not to Pages.

WordPress Pages always live at the "top" of the URL tree. /about /whatever /etc. Posts live wherever the custom permalink string defines them to be.

So, in your case, your permalinks custom structure would be "/news/%postname%/" and would not affect your Pages permalinks of "/about" and "/resources".

For instance, to put all Posts under the sub-directory "/blog", your permalinks custom structure would be "/blog/%postname%/".

Comment: Turns out MAJOR modifications were made to posts.php and index.php and that's why none of the changes I tried were working. This reaffirms how it's *supposed* to work!

Comment: I created a new site using DesktopServer, created a page and checked. It wasn't using /about, but rather /?id=2143. If I changed the permalink setting to Post Name, then it was /about. The structure affects both, it is just that pages have no category and hence this part isn't included

Comment: A non-default case turns on "pretty" permalinks, true, but it doesn't change the way the links work for anything but Posts. Pages always live at the top hierarchy.

Comment: Is it possible to have a different structure for pages? I really need that too.. I asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432586/wordpress-page-link-filter/27434179 but I got a couple of wrong answers..

Comment: You would need to modify the rewrite rules to account for your modified structure and redirect them to the pages. How complex this would be would depend on what you want your new rule to be and how it needs to fit into the existing structure.

Comment: Careful here - the settings->permalink screen also applies to custom post types, NOT just posts!

Comment: No, custom post types can have their own rewrite definitions, set by the register_post_type function.

Comment: 'The custom permalink field only applies to Posts' -> dreamy took me a more than a little googling to find that out. Thanks!